# How to express a complex operation in assembly 8086

Tags: math, assembly, emu8086

Hi guys I hope you are doing great. I am learning assembly by my own. And I Wonder how can I express a complex math expression. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5dWd.jpg)

I tried to do this. I tried to assign a register for each number, but the MUL instruction saves the Result. Does someone have an idea on how can I express this whole expression step by step? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elh42.jpg)

I did a mistake while copying the exercise the ecuation  is the following [image]

Comment: exactly the same way as you did on paper - calculate partial result, put it aside in separate register or memory location, calculate another part, preserve, then repeat

Comment: When you say "complex operation" do you mean an operation that has many steps, or do you mean an operation done on complex numbers?

Comment: You probably want to use IMUL (signed multiply) rather than MUL (unsigned multiply) and probably want a size larger than 8 bits.  (MUL/IMUL support 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit multiplies)  IMUL is also more flexible, allowing any register to be used for the dest rather than only allowing AL/AX/EAX/RAX.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Note the [emu8086] tag.  It emulates something between 8086 and 186, so the largest operand-size is 16-bit.  (Thus a 32-bit product, but only 16-bit inputs).  I don't know if it supports `imul cx, cx, 3` or whatever (a 186 instruction), but it won't support `imul cx, cx` because that was new in 386.  So they'll need `mov cx, ax` or similar to save the product for later use.

Comment: It's interesting that almost all the multiplies in their expression are squaring.  (Except for `2*` which doesn't count since it's just a left shift.)  Also weird that all the numbers are constants, so you could just write this expression in the asm source, like `mov ax, 2*(4*4*4+7*7) + ...` and let the assembler evaluate it for you at assemble time.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments they help me a lot

Comment: Seriously I'm not talking with sarcasm

Answer (score 2):

To convert a complex math expression into assembly language there are 8 easy steps:

a) Use "pen and paper maths" to reduce the expression into it's simplest form. For a random example, if the complex expression is "x = (y+3)<sup>2</sup> + 4/2 + 2" you might do:

```
    x = (y+3)*(y+3) + 4/2 + 2
      = y*y + 3*y + 3*y + 9 + 4
      = y*y + 6*y + 13
      = (y+6)*y + 13
```

b) Split the (simplified) expression into multiple small expressions by substituting pieces with intermediate variables; such that there is one operator per small expression. For example, "x = (y+6)*y + 4" would become:

```
temp1 = y + 6
temp2 = temp1 * y
x = temp2 + 13
```

c) Write the comments. For the above example it might look like:

```
;Calculate x = (y+6)*y + 4

        ;temp1 = y + 6
        ;temp2 = temp1 * y
        ;x = temp2 + 13
```

d) Add starting and ending conditions to the comments. This might be derived from calling conventions (if its a separate function) and might depend on previous code (if it's part of a larger function).  For the above example it might look like:

```
;Calculate x = (y+6)*y + 13

        ;bx = y

        ;temp1 = y + 6
        ;temp2 = temp1 * y
        ;x = temp2 + 13

        ;ax = (y+6)*y + 13
```

e) Add information about ranges and data types to the comments. Note that when you gain experience this might be optional; but it's good practice to avoid bugs (integer overflows, etc). For the above example it might look like:

```
;Calculate x = (y+6)*y + 13

        ;bx = y            (integer, range -100 to +100)

        ;temp1 = y + 6     (integer, range -94 to +106)
        ;temp2 = temp1 * y (integer, range -9400 to +10600)
        ;x = temp2 + 13    (integer, range -9396 to +10604)

        ;ax = (y+6)*y + 13 (integer, range -9396 to +10604)
```

f) Find suitable instructions that do what the comments say. For the above example it might look like:

```
;Calculate x = (y+6)*y + 13

                    ;bx = y                    (integer, range -100 to +100)

    lea ax,[bx+6]   ;ax = temp1 = y + 6        (integer, range -94 to +106)
    imul bx         ;dx:ax = temp2 = temp1 * y (integer, range -9400 to +10600)
    add ax,13       ;ax = x = temp2 + 13       (integer, range -9396 to +10604)

                    ;ax = x = (y+6)*y + 13     (integer, range -9396 to +10604)
```

g) Test that it works (Does the assembler give you an error? Does it give you the right result when its executed?)

h) Look for opportunities to optimize it or improve it more. For the above example (from Peter's comment below), an `imul bl` (instead of the `imul bx`) will work fine because both input value-ranges are small.  It avoids clobbering `dx`, which may make things easier/faster if code before or after this code needs `dx`, and makes the code a little cleaner.

`imul ax, bx` also avoids writing DX, but requires a 386 or later CPU.  It has the same output value-range as `imul bl`, but allows either input to be wider than a byte.  If you needed the wider input value-range before 386, you're stuck with `imul bx`.

Comment: Note that `imul r16, r/m16` requires 386, but this is an [emu8086] question, not 16-bit mode for a modern x86.  Normally you'd have to use `imul bx` to produce a result in `DX:AX`.  Or if you only care about the 16-bit result in AX, `mul bx` is [a bit faster on actual 8086](https://www2.math.uni-wuppertal.de/~fpf/Uebungen/GdR-SS02/opcode_i.html).  (Same AX result, but writes DX with a different high-half if either input was negative.)  Or in this case `imul bl` since your input ranges are small enough to both fit in signed bytes.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Thanks - I didn't like having no example for the last step, and your `imul bl` seems like a nice way to fix that :-)

Comment: Your point (h) is oddly stated.  The 386 instruction `imul ax, bx` doesn't clobber DX either, and your answer doesn't mention `imul bx` which does.  (`imul bl` *is* faster than `imul ax, bx` on 386/486, and same speed on Pentium and later, unlike wider one-operand multiplies which are slower from having to write a 2nd register).  I think you meant to write `imul bx` in your code block, since the comment matches that, not the `imul ax, bx` that's still there.

Comment: In the first step, you left out a "+ 9".

Comment: You're both right (originally should've been `imul bx`, and I did overlook a `+9`). This is what I get for skipping step g). Fixed I hope :-)